# Move through string in textbox using the right key wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

[Screenshot of textbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aDOS.png)

The textbox could have 250 max characters in it. The textbox size will be too small to show all 250 characters at once.

Is there a textbox property that moves the string across when the user press the right key?
or is there a textbox property that allows the user to scroll through the whole text box?

Comment: You could set Textbox's MaxWidth property and TextWrapping set to Wrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here are the properties you should set:

```
 <TextBox MaxLength="250"
          TextWrapping="NoWrap"
          HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"/>
```

'HorizontalScrollBarVisibility' is just an optional, you don't really need that, it works fine even without it